# Azure App Service attach virtual disk for a Docker MongoDB image

Tags: mongodb, docker-volume, docker-container, azure-app-service-plans, azure-disk

I'd like to know if it's possible to attach and expose a virtual disk on Azure App Service.
The goal is to host a Docker container for MongoDB on this App Service (I don't want to use a VM please because I really love the PaaS mode on Azure), but use a volume to an external virtual disk to store my datas.
In this way, I could benefit of all advantages of an Azure Virtual disk (backup…).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it’s not possible to mount/share virtual data disk on Azure WebApp, suggesting you check this below for details on deploying a docker WebApp in WebApp for containers.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-docker-go